remove Blogger home link on static page
How to remove or hide Blogger home link on static page.
I have tried different coding, nothing works.  I created a gallery on one of my pages and I want to remove or hide the home button at the top of the page.

Some examples of what you tried would help others to help you. At the moment, your question is vague. I have no idea what kind of answer you want here, it's a determined static page? all static pages? you want a javascript solution? a css solution? without clarifying your question, and if possible with some coding you've tried, don't expect much help because we don't know what you want, what you tried, and no idea where to begin to we want to help you.
